# Understanding weak pointers in block

Tags: objective-c, pointers, callback, objective-c-blocks, weak-references

The following function will not print "nil1" or "nil2" if I call it once. 
However, if I put it in a loop, some iterations will print "nil2" **ONLY**.

What's going on? If user is nil, why "nil1" is not printed?

After remove the __weak directive before the declaration of "weakUser", the function will no longer print "nil" even though it is called multiple times in a loop.

Any ideas of what's going on?

```
- (void)hello: (void(^))callback
{
    User *user = [[User alloc] init]; // user is not nil 

    __weak User *weakUser = user; // removing __weak won't cause problems.
    if(weakUser == nil)
    {
        NSLog(@"nil1");
    }
    [ABC func: ^{
        if(weakUser == nil)
        {
            NSLog(@"nil2");
        }
        callback();
    }];
}
```

Comment: why the `"nil1"` should be printed? the `weakUser` is not `nil` at all, you just instantiated the object with a strong pointer _in the same scope_ a line above which the `user` points... the `"nil1"` will be never printed in this scenario.

Comment: the `"nil2"` is printed only if the `user` is released _before_ your block runs. you can count on the `user` will be `nil` immediately when your method is finished, but there is no info about _when_ the block runs exactly in this context, aka _after_ your method is done or _before_.

Comment: if you remove `__weak` from `weakUser`, that pointer will be `__strong` automatically and your block keeps the object alive via `weakUser` until the block is released.

Comment: @holex good point on the block may execute after user gets deallocated when the "hello" call runs out of scope. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

that is a scheduling issue here, so let us just examine your code from perspective of *time*. I've added some timestamp marker to your code and let us walk through what really happens at those checkpoints.

```
- (void)hello: (void(^))callback {
    // TIMESTAMP(A)
    User *user = [[User alloc] init]; // user is NOT nil 

    // TIMESTAMP(B)
    __weak User *weakUser = user;

    // TIMESTAMP(C)
    if(weakUser == nil) {
        NSLog(@"nil1");
    }
   
    [ABC func: ^{
        // TIMESTAMP(D)
        if(weakUser == nil) {
            NSLog(@"nil2");
        }
        callback();
    }];

// TIMESTAMP(E)
}
```

we can agree in **(A) < (B) < (C) < (E)** and there are two more scenarios here

1. **(C) < (D) < (E)** or
2. **(C) < (E) < (D)**

there is no more information about which one of the two scenarios happens with **(D)**.

---

## (A)

you instantiate a `__strong User * user` in this scope, the end of the scope is at **(E)** therefore your `__strong` pointer will keep the instance alive in this context to the end of the scope. you have one retaining reference to your object.

## (B)

you make a `__weak User * weakUser` pointer, that points to a `__strong` reference what you just established recently at **(A)**. the `__weak` pointers point to an instance as long as it is kept alive by a `__strong` reference at least, but they are not retaining references – they become `nil` immediately when no more `__strong` reference points to the instance.

## (C)

you still have a valid `__strong` reference to your `user` and the `__weak` reference point to the same instance shamelessly, so the instance is still alive and the `weakUser` is not a `nil`, therefore the true-branch of `if` will *never* run – nothing will be printed ever.

## (E)

the scope runs out and the `__strong` reference to your instance won't be live anymore, therefore it does not keep the `user` alive after that point. additionally the `weakUser` immediately becomes `nil`, because that is not a retaining reference and mo more `__strong` pointer keeps the `user` alive.

---

scenarios for **(D)**:

## 1. (C) < (D) < (E)

the block runs *before* the time **(E)** is reached, the `__strong` pointer still keeps the instance alive and the `weakUser` still points to the same instance, therefore the true-branch of `if` won't perform.

## 2. (C) < (E) < (D)

the block runs *after* the time **(E)** is reached, the `__strong` pointer is not live anymore, so the instance has been released by now and the `weakUser` is `nil`, therefore the true-branch of `if` performs in this scenario.

---

*NOTE: you can read more about encapsulation and ownership on the [Apple's official site](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/EncapsulatingData/EncapsulatingData.html).*